# Possible to have template unit test methods in MSTest?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2019, mstest

Using `Visual Studio 2019`, C# and the `MSTest` unit testing framework (v2.2.10). Say I have the following template function defined in my C# `MSTest` project:

```
[TestMethod]
[DynamicData(nameof(TestData_Template), DynamicDataSourceType.Method)]
public void String_DoesSomething_ExpectsSomeResult<T>(T input, string expected)
{
    // Testing a template test method in MSTest (C#)

    // Arrange, act, assert
    string expectedLibrary = SomeLibrary.SomeFunction(input);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, expectedLibrary);
}

// Generator method
private static IEnumerable<object[]> TestData_Template()
{
    // Generate some dynamic test data
    yield return new object[] { (int)7, "7" }; // Integer
    yield return new object[] { 0.123f, "0.123" }; // Float
}
```

Compiles fine, but the `Test Explorer` is not picking up the test method(s). If I specialise on `int` or `float` as follows, `Test Explorer` picks up the methods and they work:

```
[TestMethod]
[DynamicData(nameof(TestData_Int), DynamicDataSourceType.Method)]
public void String_DoesSomething_ExpectsSomeResult_Int(int input, string expected)
{
    // Arrange, act and assert
    string expectedLibrary = SomeLibrary.SomeFunction(input);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, expectedLibrary);
}

private static IEnumerable<object[]> TestData_Int()
{
    // Dynamic test data...but this time int only
    yield return new object[] { (int)7, "7" };
}
```

The library method being tested (`SomeLibrary::SomeFunction` in this example) is correctly defined and works fine. I want to use a generator method which is self-contained, and not long sets of constant input data using the `DataRow` attribute (`MSTest`).

- Are template methods possible in (`MSTest`) unit test projects?
- Are they possible in other C# unit testing frameworks like `NUnit` or `xUnit`?

#### UPDATE

As suggested in one of the answers, `DataRow` can be used to provide a constant set of test input data. This is not working for me, so the answer may have been targeting a different version of `MSTest` or `Visual Studio`.

However, `DataRow` is not what I'm looking for. Even assuming `DataRow` works with template methods, anything except small sets of input data would be clumsy. Writing detailed comments explaining the what and why of the input data would be messy and unmaintainable.

I'm looking for a way to using generator methods with template unit test methods, as in the question.

Comment: Hi, is there any new development about MSTest using template method?

Comment: @GetValue: URL for the issue is https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/MSTest-does-not-support-template-test-me/10295790.

The issue is now "Under Consideration" at Microsoft. Hopefully that means it will be addressed, but there is no indication of timescale. Head over to the issue and upvote, though, to help the issue along.

Comment: Ok, I'm following this issue too.

Answer (score 0):

After checking the latest C# unit test frameworks, the following is correct about template methods at the time of writing:

- Work in `NUnit` v3.13.3
- Work in `xUnit` v2.4.2
- Template test methods are NOT working in `MSTest` v3.0.2

@wenbingen-MSFT gives working examples for `NUnit` and `xUnit` with constant sets of input data. This answer demonstrates the same examples with dynamic input test data using generator methods:

**In NUnit v3.13.3**

```
[Test, TestCaseSource("TestData_Template")]
public void String_DoesSomething_ExpectsSomeResult<T>(T input, string expected)
{
    // Testing a template test method in NUnit with dynamic test data

    // Arrange, act, assert
    string expectedLibrary = SomeLibrary.SomeFunction(input);
    Assert.Equal(expected, expectedLibrary);
}

private static IEnumerable<object[]> TestData_Template()
{
    // Generate some dynamic test data
    yield return new object[] { (int)7, "7" }; // Integer
    yield return new object[] { 0.123f, "0.123" }; // Float
}
```

**In xUnit v2.4.2**

```
[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(BankAccountTestData_Template))]
public void String_DoesSomething_ExpectsSomeResult<T>(T input, string expected)
{
    // Same as the NUnit example
}

public static IEnumerable<object[]> TestData_Template()
{
    // Same as the NUnit example
}
```

While this is not working in `MSTest` (v3.0.2 in Feb 2023), presumably Microsoft will get this working in a future release.

#### UPDATE

The issue has been [reported to Microsoft](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/MSTest-does-not-support-template-test-me/10295790). At the time of writing (2023-03-16) the problem is "Under Consideration".